# Square fitting on a dataset

Tags: curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have set of 2D points.

[image]

These points are basically formed from scanning a square-cuboid (if that's a thing?) and is able to rotate. So the points formed can be in any "angle" from 0 degrees to 45 degrees.

[image]

I know the dimensions of the square. How can I fit the square on these points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. Below is a rough outline of the algorithm :

1. Get convex hull of the point cloud
2. Get the indices of these hull points by Kd-Tree
3. Extract the points between the hull points
4. Apply SACSegmention for line model
5. Calculate parallel line for the line detected (In my case, I actually need a perpendicular bisector)

Below is the final result

[image]